# UISegmentedControl tintcolor can not work after setting backgroundImage

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

When we do not alter the background image of UISegmentedControl,setting the tintcolor can work perfectly.But once we change the background image, not matter which color we set for the tintcolor,the UIsegmentControl selected color will show up in grey color.How can I solve this problem without customizing a new class?

Comment: Please share your UI screen after setting background inage so that we clear more about question

Comment: thank u so much for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self.segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue.png"]
                                     forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                   barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [self.segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"]
                                     forState:UIControlStateSelected
                                   barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

### Output:

[image]

### GitHub link:

https://github.com/k-sathireddy/SegmentedControlBackgroundWithTint